# Which Moshiach are we waiting for?

Tags: rambam, messiah, ikarim

The Rambam lists waiting for Moshiach as one of the [13 principles of faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides#The_13_principles_of_faith). We have a tradition that there will be two Moshiachs, Ben Yosef and Ben David, which one was the Rambam referring to?

Comment: I'm gonna go with _both_.

Comment: @SethJ but doesn't he say to be mechakeh LO (singular)?

Comment: I thought anyone with oil on their head is a messiah. So why only one? Looks like rabam got too much christian influence?

Comment: @jim what?? If I pour oil on my head I become the messiah?? I think you've got your facts a little confused!

Comment: @HodofHod Jim is somewhat right. Any King or Kohein Gadol can be called Mashiach. It happens all over Tanakh. You forget what the word messiah means.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Not really. See my first paragraph here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22274

Comment: @HodofHod So, yes really. Are you blaming Jim ("what??") for not following your convention and using words properly? It's Chaval when people fail to distinguish between the king who will restart stuff and all his descendants and the future Kohanim gedolim etc. who will also probably have among their ranks some impressive personas. You'll notice I also pressed you on this point in the comments there.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Not really" referred to my forgetting the concept, not the concept itself. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I did not blame Jim for not following some convention (I think I meant "a messiah" and not "the messiah"). I suppose my main issue was that Jim took a two seemingly conflicting ideas (his view of anointing and this question) and [started attempting resolutions (negative ones)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=11443857#11443857) rather than just asking. Guessing at last year's motive, I think I was trying to motivate him to _ask_ a question about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the notion of R. Saadia Gaon, found in [Emunos V'Deos 8:5](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/kapah/8-2.htm#5). that the MBY is not a sure thing, I'll go with MBD.

http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/mashiach/11.htm

> "Quite significantly, R. Saadiah Gaon (one of the few to elaborate on the role of Mashiach ben Yossef) notes that this sequence is not definite but contingent! Mashiach ben Yossef will not have to appear before Mashiach ben David, nor will the activities attributed to him or his death have to occur. All depends on the spiritual condition of the Jewish people at the time the redemption is to take place:"

Answer (score 6):

The 13 principles of faith found at the end of the morning service are a revised version of Rambam's more detailed formulation of the of Foundations of the Faith, which he published in his commentary to the Mishna, as an introduction to Perek Chelek in Sanhedrin. This being the case, it is always worthwhile to check [the original](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%28%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3%29#.5B.D7.A9.D7.9C.D7.95.D7.A9.D7.94_.D7.A2.D7.A9.D7.A8_.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A7.D7.A8.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.AA.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.94.5D) regarding any questions about the meaning of any particular principle.

In this case, if we say the Rambam was referring only to Mashiach the person, it would seem that he refers to Mashiach ben David, since he ends off saying that included in this principle is the assertion שאין מלך לישראל אלא מבית דוד ומזרע שְׁלֹמֹה בלבד; that there is no king to Israel but from the house of David and the seed of Solomon alone.

However, I must add that from the gist of his words it would seem that the belief required of us is not simply about a man, but about an era. The belief that a person will help usher in that era is certainly part of it, but the main idea is a belief about the overall picture. As he starts off the principle: היסוד השנים עשר, ימות המשיח; the twelfth foundation, **the days of** the Mashiach.

Comment: What happen if you don't believe one or more of those faith? You go to hell?

Comment: @JimThio Something like that. Everyone will tell you something else. However, Judaism and Rambam in particular assert that the highest level of living is not to think so much about heaven and hell but rather to do the right thing because it is what God wants.

Comment: @jim additionally, these beliefs are (as far as i know) there only required for Jews.